# child div blocks with class names using emmet

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I want to have nested div blocks with class names using Emmet codes but I cannot figure it out.

Something like this:

```
<div class="map">
    <div class="cardcontainer">
    </div>
</div>
```

I know div>div will produce a nested div block and I can do  .map+.cardcontainer to produce two sibling divs, but .map>.cardcontainer does not work.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.map>div.cardcontainer
```

works for me.  And the intellisense in vscode as you type that is great.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
.map>.cardContainer
```

Then press `tab`.

when you use **`.`**, `emmet` will automatically convert it to a `div` element, so there is no need to write `div`.

The **`>`** symbol (with no `'white space'`) is to nest the upcoming `.className` or `HTML` element.

Also, it's common practice to use: `'camel case'` when declaring a name more than one-word class names, like so: `class="cardContainer"`. Or just separate them via `-` like so: `class="card-container"` (generally `'camel case'` is used more commonly in **styling** declarations not in **function** declarations).

This makes your code much easier to read, especially when you have a long class/variable/function name, and many lines of code to read through.

Hope that helped :)
Cheers!